# How to show the english translation, if you didn’t find the translate in the selected language file?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I have two locales: ru, en.

How to show the english translation, if you didn’t find the translate in the selected language file?

My i18n settings:

```
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    strategy: 'no_prefix',
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'ru',
        name: 'Russian',
        file: 'ru-RU.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'en',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      }
    ],
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: false,
    },
    differentDomains: false,
    forwardedHost: false,
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    parsePages: false,
  },
```

Currently showing the string with the field name in json file.

Comment: You use any variable in the url that matches la current active language? If yes you can change the text based on url params

Answer (score 0):

In the desired page or component, you can call it inside the created lifecycle as:

```
created() {
  this.$router.replace(this.switchLocalePath('en'));
}
```